# I can't find a way to pause a countdown Timer in React ( Clear Interval doesn't seems to work)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to get my Hands dirty building a Pomodoro Clock. I'm now at the point of trying to pause the timer, but i'm having an hard time doing it.
this is the constructor in the main App component:

```
this.state ={
      breakValue: 5,
      sessionValue: 25,
      time: 25*60*1000,
      isRunning: false
    }
```

Now, the time is ticking with this function :

```
countDown = (timeLeft ) =>{

  this.setState({

    time : timeLeft-1000,


  })
```

and i've passed this function through props to the Controls component :

```
countDown={this.countDown}
```

In the Controls component i've handled that function like this:

```
handleStart = () =>{
 this.props.countDown(this.props.time);
    }
```

And i did a separate function for the SetInterval:

```
interval = () =>{
   setInterval(this.handleStart,1000)


}
```

Finally i've attached to the onClick button the final function:

```
handleSetInterval= () =>{
    this.interval();

}
```

Now the timer is ticking and the countdown is working. But how to pause this counter at any time? I have another button with the pause function, and i've tried to write a function with clearInterval but it doesn't work. Shall i use a boolean logic to start/stop, or maybe handle the clearInterval inside the Main App component? I'm totally lost. Thank you guys for any answer.

Comment: `clearInterval` is the correct way to stop the timer. Please include your attempt to it, and a clear indication of what went wrong; "doesn't work" is not a useful statement of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that this wont be a super accurate timer as setIntreval goes onto the queue so its callBack is not invoked immediately at 1000ms (it just means it will be queued to do so every 1000ms)

Working snippet (per your specifications look at the second example for possibly better practices):

```js
class Controls extends React.Component{
    state={
        myInterval : null
    }
    startTimer = () => {
        this.setState({myInterval : setInterval(this.props.countDown,1000)})
    }
    stopTimer = () => {
        clearInterval(this.state.myInterval)
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Start</button>
                <button onClick={this.stopTimer}>Stop</button>
                {this.props.time}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


class App extends React.Component{
    state ={
        time: 25*60*1000
    }
    countDown = () => {
        this.setState({
            time : this.state.time-1000,
        })
    }

    render(){
        return <Controls time={this.state.time} countDown={this.countDown}/>
    }
}





ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id='react'></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

A better/best practice would be to move everything related to the counter into your counter component

If you need access to this.state.time elsewhere in your App consider useContext or Redux (according to React team for App level management of state that changes frequently try to use Redux over useContext which is the case here).

setState() at the App component level will likely re-render everything in your app every time its updated (in this case approximately every 1000ms)

Better Example:

```js
class Controls extends React.Component{
    state={
        myInterval : null,
        time: 25*60*1000
    }
    countDown = () => {
        this.setState({
            time : this.state.time-1000,
        })
    }
    startTimer = () => {
        this.setState({myInterval : setInterval(this.countDown,1000)})
    }
    stopTimer = () => {
        clearInterval(this.state.myInterval)
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Start</button>
                <button onClick={this.stopTimer}>Stop</button>
                {this.state.time}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <Controls/>
    }
}





ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id='react'></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I have two questions: The component "Counter" could be my"Controls"? Because i have on my app the App component where i show the actual counter and the Controls component( Where i have the start and stop buttons). Also why you rendered this.props.time if you create a new state to handle the clearInterval MyTimer? it's supposed to be this.state.myTimer then?

Comment: Without seeing your full code im guessing that yes my counter here is your 'control' component as its just returning 2 buttons that start and stop the counter (i am adding this.props.time to the bottom of the counter render simply to show the result you could place this in your App component as this.state.time). the this.state.myTimer is a reference to the setInterval. adding this to state allows you to call clearInterval(this.props.myTimer).

Comment: also if you look at my second example first you will be able to understand whats happening in the first example a bit better i think (which is why i suggested putting state and methods related to the component within the component itself)

Comment: i updated myTimer to be called myInterval and Counter is now Controls

Comment: thank you very much for your help. In my case i didn't study Redux yet, so for passing the state shall i use the callback function like my first attempt?

Comment: yep! if you need app level state without using Redux or useContext ReactJS Hook you will need to use the first example i gave with state on the App!

Comment: Thank you very much! Only one last doubt that i have: to pass state between components they always told to pass parameters inside the functions like this: countDown = (timeLeft ) =>{

  this.setState({

    time : timeLeft-1000,


  })   But how is possible that the Controls component read the state even if you delete the parameter in your function? countDown = ( ) =>{

  this.setState({

    time : this.state.time-1000,


  })

Comment: You are clearing the interval that is updating the time state not the time itself